# Locate labels relative to input in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem to place labels right before `<input>`s. I mean, labels should be at same line in row and max `<label>'`s height should be same as longest `<label>`'s height.

It should be like this
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuuGY.png)

Thanks a lot

```css
.form-group {
    height: 60px;
}

.form-group:after {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.control-label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 form-group">
            <label class="text-muted control-label" for="docType3">Option  Option  Option  Option  Option  Option   </label>
            <div>
                <select class="form-control" id="docType3">
                    <option>Option 1</option>
                    <option>Option 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 form-group">
            <label class="text-muted control-label" for="series3">Number </label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="series3" placeholder="">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
.control-label {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: bottom;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nsq62eeg/)

Comment: It's a closest one answer. 
`table-cell` property instead of `inline-block` does the trick
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

by giving min-height to your label.

```
.control-label {min-height: 40px;}
```

but in this solution will work until the data of the label is less then given height in css. if in some case the data will be more you have to increase that 40px to higher as per your requirements.